# Are AppSetting values read from memory or from the web.config file?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

If I get a value like so:

```
string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"];
```

I'm expecting that .Net (in my case MVC4) has parsed the App Settings when the App Domain was started and I'm actually reading from memory.

If that's not the case and this hits the file every time are there any guarantees of thread safety when getting AppSettings?

A quick attempt at exercising my Google-Fu has failed me.

I tend to use this mechanism to populate an instance field in the constructor so:

```
public class MyThing 
{
  private readonly string thingValue;

  public MyThing() 
  {
    thingValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"];
  }
}
```

We've recently had a scenario where an external dependency failed because they had a race condition and 'could not read config settings'.

This makes me wonder:

- is AppSettings threadsafe?
- does the readonly string pattern provide enough protection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And, as is so often the case, almost as soon as I asked this question my google-fu kicked in :/

[MSDN lists the AppSettings method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) as

```
public static NameValueCollection AppSettings { get; }
```

but doesn't actually mention thread safety.

However, [the page for the ConfigurationManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) has a section on Thread Safety which says:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

So it appears that the mechanism I listed is threadsafe. I would still be interested in seeing alternative approaches though!

Comment: I am having this question and I think the bit about whether or not the settings are cached in-memory and read therefrom every time you access them or if they are read from the file is not yet answered.